# EOF error when running dhclient command

Tags: command-line, networking, 20.04, vpn, dhclient

When I try to use `dhclient vpn_vpn` it shows an error as below:

```
root@sunimali-HP-ProBook-450-G6:/home/sunimali# dhclient vpn_vpn
cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.EnmkqhupY9 which is empty
root@sunimali-HP-ProBook-450-G6:/home/sunimali# dhclient vpn_vpn
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
PING 172.16.0.8 (172.16.0.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 172.16.0.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

`sudo dhclient`:

```
[sudo] password for sunimali: 
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.qlfvdHMZt4 which is empty
```

`sudo dhclient -v`:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/vethb36997a/4a:d3:20:cf:d8:5d
Sending on   LPF/vethb36997a/4a:d3:20:cf:d8:5d
Listening on LPF/docker0/02:42:63:cb:90:be
Sending on   LPF/docker0/02:42:63:cb:90:be
Listening on LPF/br-c9556f64d33b/02:42:2a:da:f2:f6
Sending on   LPF/br-c9556f64d33b/02:42:2a:da:f2:f6
Listening on LPF/br-6aee2e92098e/02:42:3b:4f:9f:0b
Sending on   LPF/br-6aee2e92098e/02:42:3b:4f:9f:0b
Listening on LPF/wlp3s0/40:23:43:05:11:71
Sending on   LPF/wlp3s0/40:23:43:05:11:71
Listening on LPF/enp2s0/04:0e:3c:93:62:91
Sending on   LPF/enp2s0/04:0e:3c:93:62:91
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on vethb36997a to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x9d566d03)
DHCPDISCOVER on docker0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x6b72fd42)
DHCPDISCOVER on br-c9556f64d33b to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x5376d59)
DHCPDISCOVER on br-6aee2e92098e to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x4d04584f)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.8.100 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7f5e15ca)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x86040e7e)
DHCPACK of 192.168.8.100 from 192.168.8.1 (xid=0xca155e7f)
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.8.100 -- renewal in 40481 seconds.
```

Comment: Please use copy and paste from the terminal for the error messages rather than using a screenshot.

Comment: @LoïcReynier thanks for feedback, I updated the question

Comment: Does ```sudo dhclient``` without arguments work for you? Can you please append the output of the command ```sudo dhclient -v``` to your post?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi  this is the out after sudo dhclient:  sudo dhclient
[sudo] password for sunimali: 
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.qlfvdHMZt4 which is empty

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I updated question with sudo dhclient and sudo dhclient -v outputs

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this part

> cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.EnmkqhupY9 which is empty

You can try adding your local hostname to /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 <your hostname>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you!
I had changed the hostname in the past and `/etc/hosts` still contained the old one.